# Mapping nmap <C-W>| to ,\ in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to create a key mapping for a Vim command which toggles full screen for split windows. The default command is `<C-W>|` and to return to normal split is `<C-W>=`.

I have tried to map:

- `nnoremap ,\ <C-W><S-\>`
- `nmap ,\ <C-W><S-\>`
- `<leader>\ <C-W><S-\>`

and none of them seems to work.

How can I create the key mapping?

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct key mapping to solve my issue. `<leader>\ <C-W>\|`. What happened is that the `|` character it is special in vim, therefore I have to escaped the `|`.

Comment: Right; or use the special notation `<Bar>` for it.